# Streaming audio in Python with TideSDK

Tags: python, html, tidesdk

Iam trying to stream audio in my TideSDK application, but it seems to be quite difficult. The HTML5 audio does not work for me, neither does video tags. The player simply keeps loading. I've tested and confirmed that my code worked in many other browsers.

My next attemp was VLC via Python bindings. But without any confirmation I do believe you need to have VLC installed for the vlc.py file to work?

Basically, what I want to do is play audio in a sophisticated way (probably through Python) and wrap it in my TideSDK application. I want it to work out of the box - nothing for my end users to install.

Iam by the way pretty new the the whole python thing, but I learn fast so I'd love to see some examples on how to get started!

Perhaps a quite quirky way to do it would be by using flash, but I'd love not to.

For those of you who are not familiar with TideSDK, its a way to build desktop applications with HTML, CSS, Python, Ruby and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The current version has very old webkit so because of that the HTML5 support is lacking. Audio and video tags are currently not supported in windows because underlying webkit implementation (wincairo) does not support it. Wa are working on the first part to use the latest webkit. once completed we are also planning to work on the audio/video support on windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I guess VLC is the easiest way for now then. People tend to have it installed anyway, and it seems to work seamlessly on both Windows and Mac OS. Dependencies sucks in my opinion, but it seems to be the safest way around!
Do you have any idea when a new version will be released? :)

Comment: If you are planning to play audio within TideSDK, you can still do the same using the Ti.Media module of TideSDK.

Comment: I've tried that, but I cant get it to work with streaming audio.

Comment: You can have look at the API documentation and sample code in the tools/drillbit folder of the repository. Try giving another try whether there is any issue with the way you are using the apis.

If it does not work out. Can you please file an issue with tidesdk github. Please try specifying what is the exact issue you are getting with all details related to platform / os. Provide some sample code to backup your issue.